# Timer in Silverlight

Tags: .net, asp.net, silverlight, timer

Is there another Timer object that can be used in Silverlight except for the System.Threading.Timer object?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check out the DispatcherTimer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(VS.95).aspx

Comment: This is the recommended way by Microsoft, see MSDN How To: Create a Timer - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189084(VS.95).aspx#CommunityContent

Answer (score 2):

storyboard is a timer too