# Accurate, Multithreaded Equivalent for System.Timers.Timer in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, timer

I have the following code using System.Timers.Timer in a WPF application and wish to port to Silverlight. The timer is used in WPF to poll data updates for a high-performance visualization component, hence the UI thread is running flat out.

```
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private const int TimerInterval = 10; 

    private void Start()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(TimerInterval);            
        _timer.Elapsed += OnTick;
        _timer.AutoReset = true;   
        _timer.Start();            
    }

    private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e) { } // ...
```

The specific requirement is as follows:

> I have a WPF App using System.Timers.Timer which reads / buffers data from external hardware
>   every 10ms and preprocesses, before loading into a visualization component. 
>   The client wishes to see a demo of a Silverlight version of this component 
>   to view the data at the same rate offline.
>
> To replicate the same
>   behaviour I have created a demo where dummy data is read from an embedded resource every
>   10ms and pushed into the visualization component. DispatcherTimer
>   will tick but since the UI is working hard, the GUI stutters. The GUI
>   can handle the update rate, just the reading from file/pre-processing of this data
>   which needs to be multi threaded at a rate as close as possible to 100Hz.

In short, I expect a timer to fire periodically until stopped and as close to 10ms as possible regardless of OnTick handler duration. The Ontick handler should also occur on a threadpool (or background) thread to allow data reads/processing in a multithreaded fashion.

I see there is a System.Threading.Timer in Silverlight but am unsure of the usage and how it may differ to the Timers.Timer version.

Can anyone comment on a good port to Silverlight for the above Timer code or a workaround to achieve the above requirement?

Comments/Suggestions welcome.

Best regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timer in Silverlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839875/timer-in-silverlight), [Silverlight 4 Equivalent to .NET Timer Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249513/silverlight-4-equivalent-to-net-timer-control), [Silverlight Timer-Like Functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850068/silverlight-timer-like-functionality)

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at [DispatchTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) as [shown here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/03/27/make-a-silverlight-timer-silverlight-2.aspx)

Comment: @V4Vendetta: DispatcherTimer will fire on the dispatcher thread; the OP specifically said he wanted it to fire on a background thread.

Comment: @JonSkeet precisely, my UI thread is running flat out!

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought probably the UI thread is too busy so maybe dispatcher.begininvoke would help queue it up

Comment: @V4Vendetta yes it works with a DispatcherTimer but with noticeable stuttering and lag. The timer is driving data updates for a high performance visualization app. Since the UI is flat out I wish to move polling for data changes to a background thread. In WPF it results in noticeable improvement. In SL sadly im stuck!

Comment: System.Threading.Timer?  I'm surprised that any 'high performance visualization app' has to be polled and has no means of signaling completion directly - polling for completion is 'low performance'.

Comment: @MartinJames for clarification the Timer in the WPF app reads / buffers data from external hardware every 10ms. 
The client wishes to see a demo of a Silverlight component to visualise the data at the same rate offline. 
To replicate the same behaviour I created a demo where dummy data is read from a file every 10ms and pushed into 
the visualization component. DispatcherTimer will tick but since the UI is working hard, the GUI stutters. 
The GUI can handle the update rate, just the reading from file/processing needs to be multi threaded. 
Suggestions welcome

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson what visualization component?  Is it something we can look up or some proprietary/NDA stuff?  Arranging a buffer to be available every 10ms is fairly easy - a thread could keep a producer-consumer queue of buffers 'topped up' from the disk file so that a suitable threaded timer can extract one every 10ms -that fixes the disk latency. Pushing the buffers into your component and handling the output is more dependent on the component/browser/whatever - I am clueless there - no Silverlight.

Comment: @MartinJames proprietary in-house. It's specifically an accurate timed callback on a background thread I'm interested in. I know it sounds daft but when you hit these brick walls because of a missing class in Silverlight its really irritating! :)

Comment: 'accurate timed callback'.  Can you take the callback result, queue that up and extract from the queue with an accurate timer?  That would further increase latency, but it's demo & so, presumably, it does not matter if the first frame is displayed a few 100ms late as long as there's no subsequent jitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, I used the System.Threading.Timer and wrapped it to create a similar API to the Silverlight Timer. This helps in my situation as I am dual deploying code to WPF and SL, hence was looking not only for a functional equivalent but ideally code I could use in both scenarios.

The below is tested as working but doesnt provide all the features of System.Timers.Timer (such as synchronisation). I'm sure it wouldn't be too difficult to add using the Dispatcher if anyone is so inclined!

I have [blogged about this here](http://goo.gl/ILmFK) (as well as a drop-in replacement for Stopwatch).

Thank you for your comments & suggestions anyway, they are very much appreciated.

Best regards,

```
namespace System.Timers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Drop in Silverlight compatible replacement for the System.Timers.Timer
    /// Doesn't do synchronisation
    /// </summary>
    public class Timer
    {
        private readonly uint _interval;
        private System.Threading.Timer _internalTimer;
        private const uint MaxTime = (uint)0xFFFFFFFD;

        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Elapsed;

        public Timer(uint interval)
        {
            _interval = interval;
        }

        public bool AutoReset { get; set; }        

        public void Start()
        {
            Stop();
            _internalTimer = CreateTimer();            
        }        

        public void Stop()
        {
            if (_internalTimer != null)
            {

                _internalTimer.Change(MaxTime, MaxTime);
                _internalTimer.Dispose();
                _internalTimer = null;
            }
        }

        private Threading.Timer CreateTimer()
        {
            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(InternalTick);
            timer.Change(_interval, AutoReset ? _interval : MaxTime);
            return timer;
        }

        private void InternalTick(object state)
        {
            var handler = Elapsed;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got following answe3r from msdn forum

One way is to use an Animation timer instead of a System.Threading timer. Here are a couple of blog posts describing it...

http://blogs.msdn.com/jstegman/archive/2007/05/05/mix-createfromxaml-and-timer-sample.aspx

http://www.andybeaulieu.com/Home/tabid/67/EntryID/70/Default.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've updated my Q to more clearly state the need to decouple from the UI thread. Any thoughts?